# send mail in web page

Tags: html, visual-studio, email

I coded web page using html in visual studio 2008 to send mail using this web page i used but when i click send it, it opens microsoft outlook without sending it. My html code

Note - I need to do this by only using html no php or else

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Let'sGo.LK</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/elegant-press.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="scripts/elegant-press.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if IE]><style>#header h1 a:hover{font-size:75px;}</style><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-container">
<header>
<h1 align="center" class="style1" 
    style="font-family: Algerian; font-size: 14mm; font-weight: 200;">AN INFORMATION 
    SYSTEM FOR NAVIGATION OF VEHICLES IN CONGESTED ROAD NETWORK</h1>
</header>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
<div id="sub-headline">
  <div class="tagline_left"><p id="tagline2">Tel: +94776106030 | Mail:
    <a href="mailto:email@website.com">Let&#39;sGo.LK@gmail.com</a></p></div>
<br class="clear" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
<div id="nav-container">
<nav> 
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">DOMAIN</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="domain.html">Literature Survay</a></li>
        <li><a href="domain1.html">Research Gap</a></li>
        <li><a href="domain2.html">Research Problem</a></li>        
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">MILESTONE</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="full_width1.html">Project Proposal</a></li>
      <li><a href="full_width2.html">SRS Presentation </a></li>
      <li><a href="full_width3.html">Prototype Presentation</a></li>
      <li><a href="full_width4.html">Final Trial</a></li>
      <li><a href="full_width5.html">Final Presentation</a></li>
      <li><a href="full_width6.html">Viva</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
      <li><a href="documents.html">DOCUMENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="presentation.html">PRESENTATIONS</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <!--<li class=" active last"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>-->
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</nav> 
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
<div class="container1">
<br />
<br />

<div class="box">
       <div class="content">
    <h1>Headline: Contact Us</h1>
<!--<form action="#" method="post">
<noscript>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="nojs" id="nojs" /></p>
</noscript>



<br />
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="22"/>
          <label for="name"><small>Name (required)</small></label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" size="22" />
          <label for="email"><small>Mail (required)</small></label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="10"></textarea>
          <label for="comments" style="display:none;"><small>Comment (required)</small></label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form" />
          &nbsp;
          <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" tabindex="5" value="Reset Form" />
        </p>
      </form>-->

<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="mailto:sudara.soysa@gmail.com" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="username"> : name <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email"> : email <BR>
comments <BR>
<TEXTAREA NAME="COMMENTS" ROWS="10" WRAP="hard">
</TEXTAREA>
<INPUT NAME="redirect" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="contact.html">
<INPUT NAME="NEXT_URL" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="contact.html">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear">
</FORM>

<!-- END OF FORM -->

</div>



  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


</div>
<div class="main-container">
</div>

<footer>
<p class="tagline_left">Copyright &copy; 2013 - All Rights Reserved by Let'sGo,LK <a href="#"></a></p>
<p class="tagline_right">Design by Let'sGo,LK (Group - 13-077)</a></p>
<br class="clear" />
</footer>

<br />
<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send an email just using a `mailto:` link.  Clicking on it will open up the mail message in your default mail program but it is up to the user to send it.

If you want to send mail messages from your site you will need to do it server side (PHP, ASP.NET, etc.)